# couldn't find file 'jquery.handsontable.full' with type 'text/css'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handsontable

I am integrating `gem 'rails_handsontable'` for my project.

In `gemfile`:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rails_handsontable'
```

In `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= requirejquery.handsontable.full
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

In `application.css`:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require jquery.handsontable.full
```

I am getting error like `couldn't find file 'jquery.handsontable.full' with type 'text/css'`.

Comment: use 
//= require handsontable.full in application.js 
and
 *= require handsontable.full in application.css

It worked after making that change